# Add column to DB2 query from other query

Tags: sql, db2, union

I have a large query that was handed to me.  After converting it to a DB2 query, I need to add a new column that will essentially provide slightly more detail from another column that is already on the query.

For instance I have Query 1 and Query 2.  I want to take Column F from Query 2 and attach it to Query 1 based on the contents of Column C.

Here is the general context of Query 2:

```
SELECT TableD.ColumnD, TableE.ColumnE, TableF.ColumnF
  FROM TableD, TableE, TableF
  WHERE TableD.ColumnD = TableE.ColumnX
    AND TableE.ColumnE = TableF.ColumnY
```

What is an efficient way to go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Can you supply your first query?  Just `join` it to the second query on `column c` and `column d` and select `column f`... Also you'd be better off using an implicit `join` vs. commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: @sgeddes I could provide the first query.  But like I said, it's very large and I don't really care to rewrite in a safe format in order to post the query on SO.  If it is really necessary, I will edit the original post.  What I will tell you is that it's a standard query with n columns pulling from 6 to 9 tables with an enormous amount of where clauses and composed of 3 sub queries using UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
with q1 as (
      <first query here>
     ),
     q2 as (
      <second query here>
     )
select q1.*, q2.f
from q1 left join
     q2
     on q1.c = q2.d;
```

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: This is perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  No need to mess around with the large query just to tack on a single, associated column.  Thank you.